# 502 Gate way gradle error: Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/ when build .apk

Tags: android, gradle, build, apk, jcenter

I am having a 502 Gateway error when gradle try to fetch artifacts from 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/. I have tried to remove the jcenter repository from my platforms/android/build.gradle file but nothing change. I also changed the configuration of my repositories but during the compilation still calling the jcenter.bintray.com that seems to be down.

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    mavenCentral()
    maven {  url "https://maven.google.com"  }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
  }
}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com" }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting? did you try accessing jcenter directly?

Comment: Replace the `maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }` with `jcenter()`. Additionally you might as well replace `maven {  url "https://maven.google.com"  }` with [`google()`](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#google-maven)